How to update Spring Security OAuth2Authentication?
I am actually updating the java version of my project from jdk11 to jdk17.
In order to do that I am also updating some dependecies like :
rg.springframework.boot from 2.1.6.RELEASE to the version 2.7.18
By doing that, the following dependencies have been updated (to the version 5.7.11):
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

My main problem is that when I try to compile the project the following classes are not found: OAuth2Authentication and OAuth2AuthenticationDetails, but I have no clue of how I should modify the code to fix the problem.
public static AuthenticatePerson getPerson(){
        String token = null;
        var person = new AuthenticatePerson();

        Authentication principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        if (principal instanceof OAuth2Authentication){
            OAuth2Authentication authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
            Object details = authentication.getDetails();

            if (details instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) {
                OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oauthsDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) details;
                token = oauthsDetails.getTokenValue();
            }
        }

        try {
            DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
            person.setName(jwt.getClaims().get("name").asString());
            person.setEmail(jwt.getClaims().get("mail").asString());
            person.setGroupe(jwt.getClaims().get("Group").asString());

        } catch (JWTDecodeException exception){
            //Invalid token
        }

        return  person;
    }

I have tried to use the following but still getting errors:
        if (principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken){
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken authenticationToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) principal;
            token = authenticationToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
        }

        if (principal instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken) {
            JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuth = (JwtAuthenticationToken) principal;
            token = jwtAuth.getToken().getTokenValue();
        }

How can I fix this?

The OAuth2Authentication class was replaced with different authentication token types in newer versions of Spring Security.
For OAuth2 resource server authentication, use BearerTokenAuthentication or JwtAuthenticationToken instead of OAuth2Authentication. These classes extend AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken. The token value can be accessed through getToken().getTokenValue()
For OAuth2 client authentication use OAuth2AuthenticationToken as the main authentication token type. Token details are handled differently in the new version.
Also don't forget to add these imports.
More info here: OAuth2AuthenticationToken vs OAuth2Authentication
